# I want subobjects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns, javascript-objects

I want to organize my JavaScript-Object in something like "submodules" and I wrote this:

```
'use strict';

var APS = (function () {

    var dashboard = (function () {
        var onReady = function () {
          alert(2);
        };

        return {
            onReady: onReady
        }
    });

    var onReady = function () {
        alert(1);
        dashboard.onReady(); // does not work
    };


    return {
        onReady: onReady,
    }
})();

$(document).ready(APS.onReady);
```

`alert(1)` does work, `dashboard.onReady()` does not work and I receive this error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: dashboard.onReady is not a function

I want to organize my code in different "subpackages" below APS to have a kind of hierachy. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Your problem can be reduced to: `var dashboard = function () {}; dashboard.onReady();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dashboard` itself is a function that hasn’t returned the object containing `onReady` yet.

Either complete the IIFE by adding another `()`:

```
var dashboard = (function () {
    var onReady = function () {
      alert(2);
    };

    return {
        onReady: onReady
    }
})(); // Calls as IIFE
```

Or use `dashboard().onReady` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You used anonymous function but not let it run to return value right away. There're two solutions for this.

1. Call the dashboard like this:

```js
dashboard().onReady()
```

2. Better one, let the anonymous function execute, notice the "()" at the end:

```js
var dashboard = (function () {
  var onReady = function () {
    alert(2);
  };

  return {
    onReady: onReady
  }
})();
```